# wso2 esb xml to json returning base64

Tags: xml, json, wso2, wso2-esb

I have a proxy service defined in ESB 4.8.1 that works just swell, returning xml.  Now I want JSON instead.  Seems simple enough.  I just add

```
<property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
```

to my inSequence.  Works, in a fashion.  I get different output.  JSON, in fact, but base64 encoded JSON.  I'd prefer text, at least for the moment, because it's easier to see what's happening.

I have another problem though.  When I decode my output, I get this:

```
{"Fault":{"faultcode":"axis2ns6:Client","faultstring":"The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is /services/profiles and the WSA Action = null. If this EPR was previously reachable, pl\
ease contact the server administrator.","detail":""}}
```

I get a proper/correct xml response if I remove the messageType="application/json" property.  Ideas?

Here is my proxy service definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="getaccount2"
       transports="https,http"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
         <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
      <endpoint>
         <address uri="http://10.2.8.1:9763/services/profiles"/>
      </endpoint>
   </target>
   <publishWSDL uri="http://10.2.8.1:9763/services/profiles?wsdl2"/>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

Comment: Could you share your proxy service definition ?

Comment: Sure, just added it to my original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define `<property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>` in your inSequence, it means that your service listening at `http://10.2.8.1:9763/services/profiles` receive a request with json payload : but in your proxy def, we can see that it's a webservice waiting for a SOAP Request.

If you want to transform the SOAP response in json in your proxy, you must move 'messageType' property definition in the outSequence, before send mediator.

Comment: Oh, I get it.  I was referring to [this example](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/JSON+Support#JSONSupport-ConvertingapayloadbetweenXMLandJSON) in the docs, but that example is transforming the request, not the response.  Starting to get the hang of it. Thanks.  This is really cool stuff.